# Can't create conda env in intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, anaconda, conda

Im trying to follow the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/conda-support-creating-conda-environment.html) on this.

According to the docs after I install anaconda the "Creating Conda environment" should just magically appear when I open intellij and go under SDKs but it does not:
[image]

Whats irritating is the docs offer zero explanation of how to configure this or why it might not appear even if anaconda is installed.

Comment: This may be work in progress (available in PyCharm, but not yet in the current IntelliJ IDEA version), see the related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26360. You can try adding it as a regular Python SDK for now.

Comment: I dont have access to view that second link. I just want to confirm the docs are wrong or Im missing something. Hard to believe they would have this feature listed in their public documentation if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The docs could be wrong, it happens, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

click on 
`python sdk`
then a new popup appears that lets you select conda env

Answer (score 1):

1.If you are using windows, run Anaconda Navigator in win.Run Anaconda Prompt.

2.Try 'conda' in cmd.see if your system can find it.

3.check if you change path to anaconda.